# Spring MVC @PathVariable tries to consume matrix parameters

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jersey

I'm in the process of migrating one of my projects from Jersey to Spring MVC, and I've ran into an issue with two of my resources, which do almost the same thing; only one is meant to fetch statistics for the customers belonging to a logged in user, while the other uses a customer ID to do the same thing.

This is what the resources originally looked like in Jersey:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Secured({Role.USER})
public List<Stat> getUserStats(@Context User user,
                               @MatrixParam("from") String from,
                               @MatrixParam("to") String to) {
    return statService.getStats(user, from, to);
}

@GET
@Path("/{cid}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Secured({Role.ADMIN})
public List<Stat> getCustomerStats(@PathParam("cid") Long cid,
                                   @MatrixParam("from") String from,
                                   @MatrixParam("to") String to) {
    return statService.getStats(cid, from, to);
}
```

`@Secured` is a custom annotation which is used to apply `ContainerRequestFilter`s to authenticate and authorize users and inject the user object used in the first resource. I'm doing pretty much the same thing in Spring MVC by extending a `GenericFilterBean`, which enables me to pass a user object as a `@ModelAttribute` to each of my endpoints. I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve this problem yet, but it works well enough for now.

My issue though, is that I've tried to implement these same functions in Spring MVC, but all requests always end up being resolved by the second of these two:

```
@GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
public List<Stat> getUserStats(@MatrixVariable String from,
                               @MatrixVariable String to) {
    return statService.getStats(null, from, to);
}

@GetMapping(path = "/{cid}", produces = "application/json")
public List<Stat> getCustomerStats(@PathVariable Long cid,
                                   @MatrixVariable String from,
                                   @MatrixVariable String to) {
    return statService.getStats(cid, from, to);
}
```

(I've left the `@ModelAttribute` out of the equation for now, so as to not complicate things needlessly.)

I'm trying to call these resources with

`http://localhost:8080/stats/from=2017-05-01;to=2017-05-31`

for users and

`http://localhost:8080/stats/12345;from=2017-05-01;to=2017-05-31`

for admins.

The latter always works, but the first leads to a `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` with the following message:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException:
For input string: \"from=2017-05-01;to=2017-05-31\"
```

I originally couldn't get matrix parameters to work at all, but some googling lead me to implement the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        urlPathHelper.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
}
```

If anyone have any ideas why the second endpoint tries to consume everything, I could definitely use some help.

Comment: Can you try to bind to map `@MatrixVariable Map<String, String> matrixVars` and extract from map
Aldo did you enable matrix variables? `<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>`

Comment: @fg78nc: I get the exact same result by binding to a map. I'm using Java config, so there's no such property readily available, but matrix variables are working in general in my project, except when they are preceded by path variables, like in this case. I've tried looking into https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-advanced-java more closely, but it seems like a slippery slope of obscure configurations that I hopefully won't have to deal with.

Comment: stats is your context path?

Comment: Yeah, so there's no problem with resolving the path, and it works perfectly without the path variable.